# Skrollr - how to make a div display:none on scroll

Tags: html, css, parallax, skrollr

Hi I'm trying to set 'display:none' on one of my elements because when it gets to the bottom it covers a button. It needs to show then display:none. Is there a way to this?

At the moment i have:-

```
            <header
                data-start="opacity: 1; "
                data-400p-start="opacity: 1; "
                data-450p-start="opacity: 0; "
                data-1699p-start="display: none;"
            >
                <div class="wrapper clearfix">

                    <div class="intro">
                        <h1><span>Innovative Studios Tailor Made</span>
                        <span>For Your Natural Habitat</span></h1>
                        <a href="contact.html" class="intro_btn">GET A FREE CONSULTATION</a>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </header>
```

With this display none at 1699p the whole div displays none from the start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can control the "display" easily enough using skrollr.  Your code could look something like this:

```
 <header
            data-start="opacity: 1; display:block;"
            data-400p-start="opacity: 1; "
            data-450p-start="opacity: 0; "
            data-1699p-start="display: none;"
        >
```

Answer (score 0):

skrollr is meant to animate the css changes like opacity. However when you list "display:none" there isn't a start point for this animation to begin. If your element covers a button, using skrollr to address this isn't ideal. You could use css to fix this (with the z-index tag for instance).